# Magento admin changes not showing up

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to remove columns in magento admin order columns but changes i made are not showing (Column is not removing)

```
//**File: /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php 
    $this->addColumn('customs', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Textfield'),
        'renderer' => 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Inline',
        'index' => 'customs',
        'filter' => false,


    ));
```

Even removing this piece of code is not removing column. (Cleared cache, Deleted Cache folder, Disabled cache, Re-indexed but still the same)

Comment: Do not edit core code. Instead, create a local module with a block that extends this class and method, and use the `$this->removeColumn('customs')` method to remove the colum. Incidentally, I can't find the "customs" column in [the core Magento block](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php) - have you been naughty...?

Comment: Nope! This also doesn't worked! thanks anyway! Any changes are not showing up. STRANGE!

Comment: Where are you putting that code? Is it in the right function? (should be `_prepareColumns()`)

Comment: Nevermind! I used the other way to remove this column. 
I used `td:nth-of-type(3) {

display: none;
}`
`th:nth-of-type(8) {

display: none;
}` 
Phew! :P

Comment: I was adding this under `protected function _prepareColumns()
    {`

Comment: check grid.php in `app/code/loca/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/`

Answer (score -1):

Please check below point.

1. Some other extension may override Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php file.
2. Or this file may be avalable in app/code/local directory.
   full path: app/code/loca/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php